# Get an array from a multidimensional array between two values

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 1523752578
            [weight1] => 1890
            [weight2] => 1760
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 1523756192
            [weight1] => 1890
            [weight2] => 1760
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 1523759807
            [weight1] => 1890
            [weight2] => 1760
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 1523763423
            [weight1] => 1890
            [weight2] => 1760
        )
)
```

How can I get an array from the array, between two [date] values?

An example, the first value is `1523756192` and the second value is `1523763423`, that should return an array containing `[1]`, `[2]` and `[3]` but not `[0]`, and the array should still contain `[weight1]` and `[weight2]`

The "to" and "from" value would come from two inputs, where a user selects two dates. Then I would select all the child arrays from the parent array that is between the two dates.

Comment: How do you know the second element is the first value, and the fourth element is the second value?

Comment: please share your try ?

Comment: The parent array is much longer, but I wanted 2 inputs where a user could select two dates, and then I would select all the child arrays that is between the two dates

Comment: do you have any sql query for this ?

Comment: It's not SQL, it's a CSV file that I've converted into a PHP array

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

```
function filterbydate($arr, $lowdate, $highdate) {
    return array_filter($arr, function($val) use ($lowdate, $highdate) {
                 return $val['date'] >= $lowdate && $val['date'] <= $highdate;
               });
}

// your data
$arr = [['date' => 1523752578,
         'weight1' => 1890,
         'weight2' => 1760],
        ['date' => 1523756192,
         'weight1' => 1890,
         'weight2' => 1760],
        ['date' => 1523759807,
         'weight1' => 1890,
         'weight2' => 1760],
        ['date' => 1523763423,
        'weight1' => 1890,
        'weight2' => 1760]];

var_dump(filterbydate($arr, 1523756192, 1523763423));
```

Please note, this retains index values, so the results will have indices of 1, 2, and 3.  If you want them renumbered, you can use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) on the resultant array - so replace the filterbydate internals with:

```
    return array_values(
            array_filter($arr, function($val) use ($lowdate, $highdate) {
                 return $val['date'] >= $lowdate && $val['date'] <= $highdate;
               }));
```